# AngularJS infinite loop of calls when calling a function?

Tags: angularjs

The title says it all. I'm calling a function in the controller and, somehow, the client keeps sending the request over and over again. Here is the function:

```
vm.user = null;
    vm.getUser=getUser;

    function getUser(id){
        $http({method:'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/'+id}).
            then(function(response){
                $scope.status = response.status;
                vm.user = response.data;
                return vm.user.login;
        }, function(response){
            $scope.status = response.status;
            vm.user = response.data || 'Request failed';
        });
    }
```

And here is the call in the html file

```
<span class="reviewUnitText">{{vm.getUser(vm.review.userId)}}</span>
```

(the function is called only once, when loading the page. No ng-repeat)
Why is it executed over and over again?

Comment: the biggest issue is that you are trying to display any content from this function. It has `$http.get` request, meaning it will **return a Promise**, that you need to resolve and not return. You should be calling it differently (by clicking on a button for example) and display whatever comes from `response.data`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey fixed it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-init`. When you place a function call inside `{{}}` then every time angular digest cycle runs this function will get executed. That is why multiple http request calls will be made.

By using `ng-init`, the function will be called only once. So you can assign the user variable from the html.

```
<span ng-init="vm.getUser(vm.review.userId)"  class="reviewUnitText">{{vm.user.login}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever angularjs renders a page it evaluates all of the expressions embedded in the final render of the page.

That means if anything on your page changes your `vm.getUser()` function will be called as the page is redrawn because something unrelated changed. If any of your functions have side effects: e.g. `vm.getUser()` updates `vm.user` this will trigger another render of the page so `vm.getUser()` will be called again.

Avoid side-effects in any expressions called from your HTML (except those from `ng-init` which only happen when an element is first rendered).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I finally understood why. Will keep this in mind for the future